# ImportError: cannot import name 'include'

Tags: python, django

I am following django official tutorial-01. After editing the `urls.py` file I got this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'include'

I have searched it here and got two solutions.

1. To update the django version
2. To include `include` in polls urls:

```py
from django.conf.urls import include
```

I have tried these two solutions, but I'm still getting the error. Does anyone have any other solution?

Here is the screenshot of the terminal:

[image]

My django version is:

> 1.11.0

Edit: This is my urls.py:

```py
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls'), name=none),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name=none)
]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you may be mixed up with the solutions.

If you are using `Django==1.11.0` then import should be as

**`from django.conf.urls import include`**

else if you are using `Django==2.x`, the import should be as,

**`from django.urls import include`**

**UPDATE**
Your code seems written in **`Django 2.x`**. So you have to update the django version and remove the `line 16` from the code

Comment: I am using django==1.11.0 and import is -
"from django.conf.urls import include"

and still got erro. I gave a screenshot. Please see that to better understand.

Comment: In your screenshot, you are using `path` , which not relevant in `Django=1.11.0`

Comment: Can you show your `urls.py` (edit your qurstion and add)

Comment: added a screenshot of urls.py

Answer (score 2):

I am using Django 3.
Remember to activate the python environment where you run the `python manage.py runserver` . To do it you run `/venv/bin$ source activate`.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced to a similar problem lately that led me to your question.

If you are using django version 4.x like me, as it is mentioned [here](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/django-4-0-url-import-error/11065/2) The url function was deprecated in v 3.1 and removed in v 4.0.

With removing line 16, line 18 could handle 'import inculde' easily.

Answer (score 0):

Using Django 1.11.0  I had the following in my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include
```

and in urlpatterns list:

```
url('',include(router.urls)),
```