# Django traceback errors

Tags: python, django, linux, pycharm, lamp

I am a beginner in python, pycharm and Linux, I want to open an existing Django project. But when I use "python manage.py runserver", I am getting a series of trace-back errors which I am attaching below.
I have installed all the LAMP stack i.e., Linux OS, Apache2 Web server,MariaDB and MYSQLclient with latest versions and have also tried updating the versions in requirements.txt. However, I haven't installed PhpMyAdmin yet, for time basis I would want to just use terminal for viewing my data tables.

Could you please explain me about the tracebacks and what can I do to run the program. It would be of great support if you can provide me with a solution.

Thank you.

Keep safe and kind regards,

SD.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you installed the python modules with pip?

Comment: Check your installed `django` version. Please check the  [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51719381/importerror-cannot-import-name-include)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Challe Yes, I did.

Comment: @hansolo I checked it. There wasn't any issue.

Answer (score 0):

The module include you are trying to import is deprecated in the django version you are using.You can may be try to import it as:

```
from django.conf.urls import include
```

Answer (score 0):

Program works now without any errors.

I have removed unused imports since one of them caused an error and replaced 'load staticfiles' since it was removed in Django 3.0. And have updated all the versions in requirements.txt to the latest versions.